# Better Way to Write ASP If Statement

Tags: if-statement, asp-classic

I have a handful of if statements in ASP and one of them looks like this:

```vb
If i Mod 120 = 0 Or i Mod 124 = 0 Or i Mod 128 = 0 Or i Mod 132 = 0 Or i Mod 136 = 0 Or i Mod 140 = 0 Or i Mod 144 = 0 Or i Mod 148 = 0 Or i Mod 152 = 0 Or i Mod 156 = 0 Or i Mod 160 = 0 Or i Mod 164 = 0 Or i Mod 168 = 0 Or i Mod 172 = 0 Or i Mod 176 = 0 Or i Mod 180 = 0 Then
```

Basically it uses `Mod` from 120 to 180 incrementing by four. There are no exceptions in it. I'm somewhat new to this and can't figure out a more streamlined way to write this code. I have other if statements like this and figure it will make the code more readable and cleaner if I can find an easier way to write this out.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please describe the actual problem you are trying to solve...

Comment: Hi @MitchWheat I'm trying to find a more efficient way to write the If statement instead of typing out every condition. I figured there was some mathematical way to calculate it since it's even increments within a set number?

Comment: No, that's your solution to some problem. What is the actual problem?

Comment: The problem is that the statement is somewhat cumbersome in how long it is. I have a couple other if statements that are long like this too. The problem is that I'm feeling like there is a cleaner way to write the code yet I can't figure out what it would be. Is this not the correct forum for that?

Comment: @MxmastaMills, you're not understanding Mitch's question. Step back a bit: why does that If statement exist in the first place? What is it meant to accomplish? What Mitch is implying, and I agree with him, is that such a complicated If statement indicates that the code might be going about things the wrong way, or at least a more complicated way than necessary. Look up "[xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)" to see what we mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `For` statement block to loop through:

```vb
For X = 120 to 180 Step 4
  If I Mod X = 0 Then
    'Do stuff
  End If
Next
```